# Find max value and delete that row in 2D array. C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I need to work with two random 2D arrays. For example one is 5x10. I can find max value in matrix, but I don`t know how to delete that row, where this max value is!

```
int max_ind(int masivs[x][y], int a, int b, int row[y], int rinda)
{
    max=masivs[0][0];
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
            if (masivs[i][j]>max)
                max=masivs[i][j];
    printf("%7d\n",max);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you limited to C-style arrays? Or can you use std::vector? It's a lot easier to "delete" a row from a vector with `vec.erase()` than it is to "delete" a row from a C-style array.

Comment: When you "delete a row," does the dimension of the matrix change? In other words, does your 5x10 matrix become 4x10 (assuming you're citing the dimensions as rows-by-columns)?

Comment: I`m just learning C and I need to make this without std::vector! Thats why I think I don`t know how to make that. Thank you @Zach Stark

Comment: Yes, when I delete this row, my matrix dimension changes to 4x10 and that row with max value is gone! @seh

Comment: Learning C or C++? Even though C++ inherits some syntax from C, they are still two different languages and the solution to a certain problem can differ by quite a loot depending on language. While it's good to learn about arrays and pointers, remember that once you are done with that you can essentially throw away that code as C++ have much better facilities for these things than C.

Comment: Sorry, I`m learning C++ now, not C, my fault!

Comment: Smth going wrong for me...@JoachimPileborg maybe you can help me with that part of code, how would it look when move the next row into the "max" row utt for decrease the row count and show the matrix 4x10 at the end. It would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the row index too, and not only the maximum value, and after the loops remove that row.

Oh, and it will be much simpler to remove a row if you use e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (like `std::vector<std::vector<int>> masivs`).

---

If you can't use `std::vector`, then you have to move the remaining rows and decrease the row count by one. This can be done by a loop that move the next row into the "max" row, the next-next row to the next row, and so on.

Comment: Ok, but now without using `for` or `while`, only <algorithm> C++11 style. Let´s have some fun! (max complexity O(n*m)). 3, 2, 1, go!